# can i make watch apps inside smart watch 4G LTE (android version 7.1.1)?

Tags: android-studio, wear-os

Can anyone tell me, can I develop a watch app in a 4G LTE smart watch? I have tried to run my project in android studio to my android watch. but there is a notification issuing
`"missing feature: WATCH on device alps DA08"`

I have also set the SDK: API 25: Android 7.1.1 (Nougat) before creating this project.

Any suggestion to solve [my problem?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yXth.png)

Comment: What is the manufacturer and device? If it's not Wear, you can still make apps, but you might find you don't have access to all possible Wear libraries and features like pairing don't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.